# In Tableau Desktop I need to find the distinct customers of 2013 in the year 2014 for the global superstore example datasheet

Tags: tableau-api

Im using the Global superstore supplied by tableau and trying to find a solution for finding  distinct customers of 2013 in the year 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps need a cohort analysis.  Do it like this-
Step-1: Create customer cohort by creating calculated field namely `customer acquisition` as -

```
{ Fixed [customer id]: MIN([order date])}
```

Step-2: Build your view by applying filter on this new field.

If you are still having any problem do tell me.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Goyal!